# Where can i find the direct-users.csv metrics file?

Tags: stats

It used to be here https://metrics.torproject.org/csv/direct-users.csv . I wanted to use it for a simulation I'm setting up, but I can't find it there nor elswhere. Does anybody know more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contents have moved here: https://metrics.torproject.org/stats/clients.csv; also look at this page for a description of the file format: https://metrics.torproject.org/stats.html.